# How to use a dictionary in `codable` response?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I have the following response from a JSON query.  How do I represent a dictionary as codable?  I have shortened the JSON response to save space.

```
{
 "result":[
            {
            "delivery_address": "",
            "made_sla": "true",
            "watch_list": "",
            "upon_reject": "cancel",
            "location": {
                "link": "https://foo.com/api/now/table/cmn_location/753ac76f4fd9320066bfb63ca310c79b",
                "value": "753ac76f4fd9320066bfb63ca310c79b"
             }
          }
    ]
}    

struct ResultList : Codable {
   let result: [Result]
}

struct Result : Codable {
    let delivery_address: String
    let made_sla: String
    let watch_list: String
    let upon_reject: String   
    let location: Location
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let link: String?
    let value: String?
}

  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  do {
      let todo = try decoder.decode(ResultList.self, from: responseData)

      print("todo \(todo)")

      } catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        print(error)

      }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: That json wouldn't give you that error

Comment: That's not the real code / JSON. Where does `Index 2` come from? And at least the JSON must be wrapped in `{}`

Comment: The full JSON response is quite lengthy and I didn't want to post it in it's entirety.  But the error indicates .location `"Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead."`

Comment: As @dan mentioned, this JSON (wrapped in `{}`) does work.

Comment: updated JSON response, and added a few fields.

Comment: Still not valid json, still wouldn't give you the error you claim to be getting (thought would give you a different error)

Comment: *The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on all the comments, I believe the JSON you're actually decoding looks more like this:

```
{
    "result": [{
            "delivery_address": "",
            "made_sla": "true",
            "watch_list": "",
            "upon_reject": "cancel",
            "location": {
                "link": "https://foo.com/api/now/table/cmn_location/753ac76f4fd9320066bfb63ca310c79b",
                "value": "753ac76f4fd9320066bfb63ca310c79b"
            }
        },
        {
            "delivery_address": "",
            "made_sla": "true",
            "watch_list": "",
            "upon_reject": "cancel",
            "location": ""

        }
    ]
}
```

So there are some records that have a location, and some that encode location as an empty string. Basically this is really messed up JSON on a whole lot of levels and whatever code generates it should be fixed. The bad news I'm sure that won't happen. The good news is we can fix it locally at least.

We're going to have to decode this by hand, so we might as well clean up all the rest of the mess while we're in here. The first thing is that the names don't match Swift naming conventions. We can fix that using `CodingKeys`. We can also provide real types (Bool and a Rejection enum) for the things that are currently mis-typed strings.

```
enum Rejection: String, Codable {
    case cancel
}
struct Result : Codable {
    let deliveryAddress: String
    let madeSLA: Bool
    let watchList: String
    let uponReject: Rejection
    let location: Location?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case deliveryAddress = "delivery_address"
        case madeSLA = "made_sla"
        case watchList = "watch_list"
        case uponReject = "upon_reject"
        case location
    }
}
```

Now we just need to be able to decode it. Notice that I made Location optional. Clearly it sometimes doesn't exist, so you either need a default value or it needs to be optional. I chose the latter. Decoding all of this is very straight forward:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    deliveryAddress = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .deliveryAddress)
    madeSLA = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .madeSLA) == "true"
    watchList = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .watchList)
    uponReject = try container.decode(Rejection.self, forKey: .uponReject)

    location = try? container.decode(Location.self, forKey: .location)
}
```

The last line is your actual question. It just says if we can't decode it as a `Location`, set it to nil. We could be stricter here and try first to decode it as a Location, and then as a String, and then check if the String is empty, but it feels reasonable to use nil here for any decoding failure.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  It works great.  Thanks to everyone else that helped to get to this point.  I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON is (please note the missing closing brace)

```
{
"result": [
    {
     "delivery_address": "",
     "made_sla": "true",
     "watch_list": "",
     "upon_reject": "cancel",
     "location": {
                "link": "https://blah/blah/foo",
                "value": "fsfdfr32r34rwfwffas"
     }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can decode these structs

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let result : [Result]

    struct Result : Decodable {
        let location: Location
    }
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    let link: String
    let value: String
}
```

with

```
JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly as you have suggested already, see updates.

Comment: Then –  once again –  the JSON is not the JSON in the question (respectively in my answer). The JSON / code in my answer works.

Comment: I can confirm you're correct.  I've found the probem.  Some of the data for `location` is not a dictionary, rather `location: ""`  I just have to figure out how to check for this.

Comment: That's nasty. It means you need to manually implement `init(from: Decoder)` and add some fallback behavior when decoding the `location` value.

Comment: @JonShier - How would I code this?  I'm searching up examples, but nothing really works for my case.?? Thanks

Comment: @PaulS. This documentation outlines custom Codable conformances: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types